# UIButton press triggers method action

Tags: objective-c, methods, uibutton

I have PhotoView class (subclass of UIButton) and I would like that when I press any button that is class of PhotoView, same action should be triggered.

I tried something like:

```
- (void)didSelectButton:(PhotoView *)sender
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `PhotoView` `init...` method, set `self` as its own target:

```
[self addTarget:self selector:@selector(didSelectButton:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Please note that this is a poor design. Your `PhotoView` should be a `UIView` that contains a `UIButton`.

Answer (score 0):

in the viewDidLoad method of your view controller you could iterate on your view subviews (and their own subviews, recursive style) in order to found instances of your PhotoView class and use addTarget on those instances.